# SQL Constraint check value exists in another column in the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table where each row is a task.
Each task has a parent (i.e. the task that instantiates it), or a null parent (task occurs at start of time).
I want to add a constraint to the parent column so that it can only take a null value or a value that already exists in the task column and is not equal to its own task.

```
tasks
=====
task (PK) | description | duration | parent
----------+-------------+----------+--------
ABC-123   | Foo         |       10 | Null     <--- OK
DEF-456   | Bar         |        8 | ABC-123  <--- OK  
GHI-789   | Baz         |       12 | ABC-123  <--- OK
JKL-987   | Boz         |        7 | Null     <--- OK
MNO-654   | Foz         |       88 | GHI-789  <--- OK
PQR-321   | Faz         |        6 | ZZZ-999  <--- Not OK; parent doesn't exist
STU-123   | Fez         |        5 | STU-123  <--- Not OK; can't be its own parent
```

How can I do this?
I want to add a constraint like:
`CONSTRAINT ck_parent_valid CHECK parent <> task AND parent NOT IN task`
..but the above obviously doesn't work because I need to refer to both the task in the current row  and the task column as a whole.

Comment: That would be a foreign key constraint. The referenced and referencing tables are allowed to be the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one way to do this is to add a foreign key constrain to the table and RDBMS automatically will check it and also you can set `cascade update` or `cascade delete` to done changes automatically without any coding. like below:

```
ALTER TABLE tasks 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_tasksParent
FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES tasks(task);
```